# set theory basic discrete math and other question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have two questions that's been bothering for hours

How to prove this:

$A \cap (B \cap C') = (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)'$

Edited: Added '

Association doesn't work because its only get to

$(A \cap B) \cap C'$

And second is about basic permutation, if there is 4 apple and 3 oranges lined in one row and on the edges of the row there should only be apple and oranges / in reversed order, How many ways can you arrange the fruits?

Comment: asdfg Do you realize that $(A\cap C)' = (A'\cup C')$?

Comment: Is that de Morgan's law? Isn't it A n C' = A' u C'

Comment: Did you mean to write $A \cap (B \cap C') = (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)'$ or $A \cap (B \cap C') = (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C')$?
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one can't go very far wrong with proving something with arbitrary elements.

$A \cap (B \cap C') = (A\cap B)\cap(A \cap C')$

$a\in A \cap (B \cap C') $ means $a \in A$ and $ a\in B\cap C'$ so $ a \in B$ and $a \in C'$.  So $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ so $a \in A\cap B$.  And $a \in A$ and $ a \in C'$ so $ a \in A \cap C'$. So $a \in (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C')$.

So $A \cap (B \cap C') \subset (A\cap B)\cap(A \cap C')$

The reverse is equally easy.  $a \in (A\cap B)\cap(A \cap C')\implies a \in A\cap B$ and $a \in A \cap C'$ so $a \in A$ and $a \in B$ and $a \in A$ (again) and $a \in C'$ so $a \in A$ (for the third time!) and $a \in B$ and $a \in C'$ so $a \in B \cap C'$ so $ a \in A \cap (B \cap C')$

So $(A\cap B)\cap(A \cap C') \subset A \cap (B \cap C')$

So $A \cap (B \cap C') = (A\cap B)\cap(A \cap C')$

====

As for your second question:

And second is about basic permutation,if there is 4 apple and 3 oranges lined in one row

I understand

and on the edges of the row there should only be apple and oranges

I do not understand.  What are the "edges of the row"?

/ in reversed order ,

Um... I really do not understand.  Or you saying if you look at another row it is in reverse order?  But you only have one row.

Oh, wait do you mean, if you look at the row from left to right you get the fruit on some order but if you look at it right to left you see the fruit in the same order?

That if the row is: ABCDEFG then A=G, B=F, C=E, D=D, E=C, F=B, G=A?

Then {ABC} = {EFG} and {ABCEFG} have an even number of each fruit so D is the odd orange.  And {ABC}={EFG} = {2 apples and 1 orange}

This breaks down to how many ways are there to do: ABCorangeCBA.  Which is the same thing as asking how many ways are there to do ABC where ABC are 2 apples and 1 orange.

How many ways can you arrange the fruits?

Comment: Why is it downvoted? This is exactly what I meant. The second question is explained there. If I could add some things it's if A for Apple and O for oranges then the line would bel ike A-----O or O-----A where between O and A / A and O is Apple and Oranges in random order.

Comment: Hmmm, fleablood, you seemed to have answered a question different from the one you answered.  The OP's last edit to the post, (after which he notified you in a comment above was asking how to prove $$A\cap (B\cap C') = (A\cap B) \cap (A\cap C)'$$

Comment: It's ok. Answer is similar. thanks @fleablood

Comment: Um, amwhy.  That is exactly what was asked and exactly what I answered.  I'm not quite sure how i, or anyone, can answer a different question then the question they answer.  That's a bit like being a different person than the person you are.

Comment: @asdfg1234 Now there is not a downvoted.